# json array and cross platform md5 encryption

Tags: asp.net, json, api, encryption, cross-platform

I have a php 'API' with JSON array that I would like to pass onto other websites to be integrated. Is there a way to use a generic md5 method that supports cross platforms (asp etc.)?

Or is there a better way to encrypt data? I can't use SSL at this point therefore I need to find some other method that is why I try md5.

Any suggestion are most welcome from the great community. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While MD5 is cross platform it is not encryption, it is a one-way non-reversible cryptographic hash function. For encryption the current standard is AES (Advanced Encryption Standard) which is also cross platform.

You will find many questions/answers here on AES for many platforms.

For cross platform encryption consider [RNCryptor](https://github.com/RNCryptor), it includes secure password derivation, encryption authentication, random iv and versioning. See [RNCryptor-Spec](https://github.com/RNCryptor/RNCryptor-Spec/blob/master/RNCryptor-Spec-v3.md) for details.

Comment: many thanks for your explanation I am going to check them out.

Comment: When I checked other people commenting the methods that you listed complained about the compatibility which one you recon the most reliable?

Comment: Compatibility is a problem and that is a strong point for RNCryptor since it is available across many platforms and languages. If you go to base AES you will find that while the encryption is compatible the implementations are not compatible in options, defaults and input/output encodings. Many do not even specify what the default options are. You would need to handle the random iv and password derivation yourself plus you get encryption authentication and it is safe from  padding oracle attacks. RNCryptor is stable, reasonably well vetted and actively maintained.